# Asynchronous tools break the chain in langchain implementation

Tags: python, microservices, langchain, py-langchain

I implemented langchain as a Python API, created via FASTAPI and uvicorn.

The Python API is composed of one main service and various microservices the main service call when required. These microservices are tools. I use 3 tools: web search, image generation, image description. All are long running tasks.

The microservices need to be called as a chain. I.e. the output of one microservice can be used as the input to another microservice (who's output is then returned, or used as an input to another tool, as required).

Now I have made each microservice asynchronous for better scalability. As in, they do the heavy lifting in a background thread, managed via Celery+Redis.

This setup breaks the chain. Why?

Because the first async microservice immediately returns a `task_id` (to track the background work) when it is run via Celery. This output (the `task_id`) is passed as input to the next microservice. But this input is essentially meaningless to the second microservice. It's like giving a chef a shopping receipt and expecting them to cook a meal with it.

The next microservice requires the actual output from the first one to do its job, but it's got the `task_id` instead, which doesn't hold any meaningful information for it to work with.

This makes the chain return garbage output ultimately. So in that sense, the chain "breaks".

How else could I have implemented my langchain execution to ensure concurrency and parallelism?

Please provide an illustrative example.

Comment: Have a shared storage / API where the 2nd service would query the object by `task_id` - I mean I'm not sure what else you are hoping to get from an answer.